# How to create different paper wallets for different currencies?

Tags: wallet, exchanges, currencies, paper-wallet

I have several different currencies (on exchange) right now and would like to move them to paper wallet.

1) Do I have to have a different wallet for each currency?

2) Are the algorithms for creating (prv, pub) different for each currency, or is it possible just to create a different pair with the same algorithm (e.g just create different pairs with [bitaddress.org](https://www.bitaddress.org/bitaddress.org-v3.3.0-SHA256-dec17c07685e1870960903d8f58090475b25af946fe95a734f88408cef4aa194.html))

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1)

It depends on the currencies you want to store. You could store Bitcoin and BitcoinCash on the same paperwallet because they use the same private and public keys. Just for a better overview I would recommend storing those on different paperwallets as well and labeling them accordingly.
**You cannot store completely unrelated cryptocurrencies on the same paperwallet.**

#### 2)

The **algorithms** to create the private key and to create the public from a private key are/can be **different for each crypocurrency** out there. You would have to find tools **for each one** you want to store on paperwallets.

Comment: Thank you @schrotti264! Would you recommend a tool for generating different paper addresses for different currencies? A safe tool (that will not steal my prv+pub) and a one the indeed will generate the appropriate address for different currency?